# Volume form on a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This is an exercise from chapter 16 of Loring Tu's "Differential Geometry" textbook.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function whose partial derivatives do not simultaneously vanish on the zero locus $Z(f)$. I have shown that the gradient vector field $\text{grad}f=\sum\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a unit normal vector field to the surface, when divided by its norm. I am then asked to compute the volume form on $Z(f)$, with the following in mind:
an orthonormal frame $(e_2,...,e_n)$ at $p\in Z(f)$ is said to be positively oriented if and only if $(X,e_2,...,e_n)$ is positively oriented for $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$.
The main way that I know of computing the volume form, is to find an orthonormal frame, take the dual frame, and then compute the interior multiplication with a unit normal vector field on the surface. In fact, other methods have not been presented in the book thusfar. However, it doesn't seem to me that I have enough information to be able to compute the volume form, explicitly. Am I mistaken? If yes, what am I missing, and if not, what else could the question be asking?

Comment: Well, do you know a vector field normal to $Z(f)$ that never vanishes on $Z(f)$?

Comment: Yes, the (normalised) gradient vector field. But would I not need more information to find an orthonormal frame $(X,e_2,...,e_n)$, as well as its dual frame?

Comment: You don’t actually need a full orthogonal basis, do you?

Comment: So there's no explicit computation, I just say that it's the interior multiplication of the gradient vector field with the volume form $\omega$, restricted to the surface, and that's it? Apologies if this sounds stupid, just a bit new to the topic and not confident in my intuition.

Comment: Yes, that’s it. The “interior product” machinery does the explicit computation for you. Indeed, you have by definition $(\iota_{\nu_f}\omega)(X_2,\ldots,X_n)=\omega(\nu_f,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$, which is exactly the determinant in any positively oriented orthonormal basis of the tangent space of $Z(f)$ of $X_2,\ldots,X_n$ – which is thus a natural volume form.

Comment: Alright, I was just looking for an explicit computation as I thought that was more in line with the rest of the problems of that section, which were far more elaborate. Thanks for clarifying, then.

Answer (score 4):

You should know the following convenient formula, which follows immediately from what you've said. If $\vec A = (a^1,\dots,a^n)$ is the *unit* normal to oriented hypersurface [I would usually use $\vec n$, but that doesn't work too well with our being in $\Bbb R^n$.], then the volume form for the hypersurface is
$$\sigma = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} a^i dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n.$$

Comment: Thanks! That one is already known to me though, as you said, it is the interior multiplication. Are you implying that I would be able to apply this formula to get an explicit result for the volume form on $Z(f)$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just use the normalized gradient for $\vec A$.

Comment: That's fair enough, I think I was overcomplicating it then, trying to find an orthonormal frame for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $e_1=\text{grad}f/||\text{grad}f||$, and such. Thanks for clearing that up.